# load local asset bundle through www

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity3D gonna develop a `standalone game` from `webplayer based game`. so the webplayer game download the assets folder from server but according to standalone no need to download assets from server. so how can i load  local bundle to run the app. i have folder name "`Bundle` " which contain the bundle package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your Bundle folder is in Assets/Resources you can use Resources.Load() to load them. AND(!) they are compiled into your game.

If you want to use WWW to load local files use file://

```
var FilePath = "file://" + Application.dataPath + "/Bundle/image.jpg";
```

And point WWW to this path.

Comment: Be careful, this is only working on OSX, Window Editor. For example on Android, Application.dataPath doesn't exist.